# Test shelved changes on demo production environment?

Tags: azure, tfs, visual-studio-2013, changeset, shelve

I'm using Windows Azure.

Is there a way to deploy the shelved changes to a demo production environment, to verify it works fine, before deploying an actual release?

Comment: Using TFS automatic build or manually?

Comment: "I'm using Windows Azure": Web sites? VM? Web Role?

Comment: Automatic continuous build with TFS.

Comment: You will need to answer CSharpRock's question if you want to get anywhere with this topic. The short answer to your post is "yes", which you will not find helpful since the next question is "OK, then how?". The answer to that depends on the question CSharpRocks asked.

Comment: @CSharpRocks, I'm deploying to azure using TFS build. I don't know what's VM and Web Role.

Comment: Likely that you're using Web Sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start a [private build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181722.aspx#Private) with shelveset using the [TFSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181742.aspx) command. E.g.:

```
TFSBuild start /shelveset:"my shelveset" /buildDefinition:"1.0_CI" \collection:http:\\tfs:8080\tfs\DefaultCollection
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to configure the trigger setting option of build definition to **Gated Check-in**.
[image]

Then, when queuing a build you will get an option to mention the shelveset details for the deployment.

[image]